# NoSuchMethod:org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion.getEP_NAME()Lcom/intellij/openapi/extensions/ExtensionPointName;

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I wrote a plugin to use lint check code. Only java code can work well, When I import kotlin code, it meets error

If i import the plugin module in project, it can work well but when i upload plugin jar to maven, other project with ktlint code import this plugin, it will report error

```
Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:incrementlint'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion.getEP_NAME()Lcom/intellij/openapi/extensions/ExtensionPointName;
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.registerAppExtensionPoints(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:145)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.createApplicationEnvironment(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:94)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.get(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:71)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.initializeProjects(LintCliClient.java:971)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.performInitializeProjects$lint_api(LintClient.kt:774)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.kt:306)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:179)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:254)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.runLint(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:250)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.lintAllVariants(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:391)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.analyze(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:85)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.task.IncrementLintGlobalTask.runLint(IncrementLintGlobalTask.kt:34)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.task.IncrementLintGlobalTask.lint(IncrementLintGlobalTask.kt:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: Hi, this may help (version mismatch) https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/195

Comment: When I use this plugin as module in project,It can work.But when i use jar from maven,it will report error NoSuchMethod:org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion.getEP_NAME()Lcom/intellij/openapi/extensions/ExtensionPointName;

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
add: classpath 'com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.3.0'
```